# JQuery selector returns unrelated array instead of dom object

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

This is by far the strangest thing I faced during all the years I've been programming.

On my page I have simple html element with id:
[image]

Then I try to reach this element by jQuery selector. Instead of an object, I get array of strings!

[image]

By the way, I'm using jqGrid and that array is Colnames of my grid. I don't know if that's related.

So, what is happening? And how can I get my DOM element?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Please edit to add code

Comment: try document.getElementById('prev_t_AvlMaterialsGrid_toppager') or $(document.getElementById('prev_t_AvlMaterialsGrid_toppager')) if you need to wrap in jQuery

Comment: Can you also make sure $ is referring to jQuery? You can also try jQuery('prev_t_AvlMaterialsGrid_toppager') just to be sure.

Comment: @Zeph docuement.getElementById(...) works fine and returns DOM element. Wrapping it in jQuery selector( $(document.getElementById(...) ) again returns the same array

Comment: @rajeshrajan that was it! Unbelievable, who would try to overwrite $ in JS

Comment: @RicoW Awesome. Been there before ;)

Comment: @rajeshrajan you can write it as an answer and I will mark it as correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that $ may not be referring to jQuery. You can use  jQuery('prev_t_AvlMaterialsGrid_toppager') to confirm that jQuery returns the appropriate selectors.